# Couldnt match expected type

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble with this code:

```
listAdd :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]

ListAdd x (y:ys) = (x+y):(foldl listAdd y ys)
```

It's supposed to add the left element of the list to it's right starting with x + the first element, the first + the second etc.

The compiler says:
`Couldnt match expected type [Int] with actual type Int.`

I don't know what the problem is. It would be great if somebody could tell me.

Comment: Is the capitalized `ListAdd` a type?  Haskell functions cannot start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change it to

```
listAdd _ [] = []
listAdd x (y:ys) = (x + y) : listAdd y ys
```

You don't need a fold at all!  Just simple recursion would do.

However, I would instead use a little trick using `zipWith (+)`:

```
listAdd x xs = zipWith (+) xs (x : xs)
```

You don't have to use any explicit recursion, and it works on any length list (no need for the special case for `[]`)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `foldl` your as passing it a function which is of type `Int -> [Int] -> [Int]` and that cannot match `a -> b -> a`, because `Int` is not the same type as `[Int]`.

What you probably want to use in this instance is `map`:

```
listAdd x ys = map (\y-> x + y) ys
```

EDIT: Also function names should not start with capitals unless your function is actually a constructor for some `data` type.